# how to make asynchrone synchrone => how to test asynchronous treatement (ie write file)

Tags: node.js, fs

I a writing unit test (mocha chai) on a file manipulation function
I am a beginner in Node.Js but used to other languages
I use typescript but sample is in JS

here is my problem:
A function writes in a file 
when the program read the file a bit later the file is empty 
when I look when the program is done the file is filled

To go fast a sample code

```
const fs = require("fs");
function test() {
    let fss = fs.createWriteStream("file.txt", { flags: 'a+' });
    fss.write("bla");
    fss.end(() => {
        fss.destroy();
    });
}
test();
let val = fs.readFileSync('file.txt', 'utf8');
console.log(val); // empty
```

But it's not the first time I meet the problem. What is the good practice : promisify, events (I don't really like everything as a callback) ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--so far it seems like any async JS tutorial would answer this.

Comment: The `fs` module has several synchronous built-in methods: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Answer (score 1):

A couple of alternatives:

1. Call the code you need when done with the write stream

   ```
   const fs = require("fs");
   function test() {
       let fss = fs.createWriteStream("file.txt", { flags: 'a+' });
       fss.write("bla");
       fss.end(() => {
           fss.destroy();
           let val = fs.readFileSync('file.txt', 'utf8');
           // do stuff here with val
       });
   }
   test();
   ```
2. Return a `Promise` in `test`

   ```
   const fs = require("fs");
   function test() {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           let fss = fs.createWriteStream("file.txt", { flags: 'a+' });
           fss.write("bla");
           fss.end(() => {
               fss.destroy();
               resolve();
           });
       });
   }
   test().then(() => {
       let val = fs.readFileSync('file.txt', 'utf8');
       // do stuff here with val
   });
   ```
3. Use the `async` / `await` syntax

   ```
   const fs = require("fs");
   async function test() {
       await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           let fss = fs.createWriteStream("file.txt", { flags: 'a+' });
           fss.write("bla");
           fss.end(() => {
               fss.destroy();
               resolve();
           });
       });
   }
   await test();
   let val = fs.readFileSync('file.txt', 'utf8');
   // do stuff here with val
   ```